# SSH into Private VM IPs on Azure

Tags: azure, ssh, network-programming, virtual-machine

I'm looking to deploy a test network on Azure with 10 VMs, a private IP per VM, in the following network stack:

`1 virtual network -> 1 subnet -> 1 network interface card (nic) -> 10 VMs`

What I want to confirm: Is it possible to give each VM a private IP address, all under the same nic, and be able to SSH tunnel into each of them, from the top-level public IP of the virtual network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to give each VM a private IP address, all under the
>   same nic?

No, this is not possible. On Azure, network interface card(NIC) is an independent resources. **A NIC only could be associated to one VM**, but you could add multiple NICs to one VM(depends on VM size). You could refer to this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-network-interface).

So, if you want all VMs use a same NIC, it is not possible.

> According to the Azure limit docs, each network interface can support
>   50 private IPs

Yes, one NIC could be associated multiple private IPs, but it does not mean that you could add one NIC to multiple VMs. You only could add multiple IPs for one NIC on one VM. Please refer to this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-multiple-ip-addresses-powershell).

> and be able to SSH tunnel into each of them, from the top-level public
>   IP of the virtual network?

Azure supports this, if your VMs are in the same VNet, you could ssh to other VMs with private IP between your VMs. As David said, you could use jump box. You could associate [Public IP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-ip-addresses-overview-arm#public-ip-addresses) to one VM. Then, when you ssh to the VM on Azure, you could ssh any VMs with private IP in the same VNet.

Comment: That makes sense, and thank you for clearing up the nic to private IP issue. Looks like I'll need to make a nic for every vm and use a jumpbox.

Answer (score 0):

With "classic" virtual machines, you'd have multiple VM's in a `xyz.cloudapp.net` namespace, all sharing the same IP address. And each VM's ssh port would be mapped to some unique inbound port on the load balancer.

With ARM-based VMs, each vm has its own network interface. With independent iP per VM.

If you wanted, you can simply not have any inbound traffic on your VMs (e.g. no IP addresses assigned). And then deploy a single jumpbox with ssh exposed, and with that jumpbox part of the same vnet. Once into the jumpbox, you'd then be able to ssh to any one of your 10 vm's.

Comment: Thanks @David. I just read up on jumpboxes, sounds like that's what I'm looking for. Why would each VM need a network interface though? According to the Azure limit docs, each network interface can support 50 private IPs, wouldn't I only need one interface to support the 10 VMs?